# With React how can I access a component's method from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that when a button is clicked it opens up a modal, the only thing is I need a button to trigger a method on a different component:

```
var QueueReveal = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { clock: "0H 0M 0S" }
    },
    componentDidMount: function(e) {
        $(document).foundation();
    },
    enterQueue: function(e) {
        $('#Queue').foundation('open');
        // Start Timer  
    },
    leaveQueue: function(e) {
        $('#Queue').foundation('close');
        var data = {
            msgType: "LeaveQueue",
            data: {}
        }
        queueConn.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="text-center">You Are Now In Queue</h1>
                <p className="text-center"><small>You will be notified when a potential party has been found</small></p>
                <span className="line-breaker"></span>
                <br/>
                <h1 className="text-center">{this.props.counter}</h1>
                <br/>
                <a className="alert button expanded" onClick={this.leaveQueue}>Leave Queue</a>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<QueueReveal/>, document.getElementById('Queue'));

var EnterQueueButton = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <a href="#" id="enterQueueButton"><i className="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Enter Queue</a>

            // I would like this link to trigger `QueueReveal.enterQueue`
        )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<EnterQueueButton/>, document.getElementById('EnterQueueButton'));
```

I would like `EnterQueueButton` to trigger `QueueReveal.enterQueue` when clicked but I'm not exactly sure how to go about this.

Comment: Just to be sure, are they completely independent components? or is one rendered inside the other?

Answer (score 0):

If they are completely independent components what I'd do is to make the components extend `EventEmitter` (something like [this](https://gist.github.com/brigand/10399638)) and make one component listen for an event and then the other component trigger it.

If you can refactor the code to have one component inside the other you can use references. You can assign a reference to a component by providing the `ref` key and then access it by `this.refs.<the name you gate it>`, this is a react component so you can call whatever you want in it. See [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)